# AccessViolationException at Xsl Transform

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

Below is the code which pefrorm the xsl transformation.
the code works fine if xslt file contains 15 or less sheets.
However when there are more than 15 sheets it gives the following error.

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

```
                    using (var tw = new XmlTextWriter(xlsFileNameWithPath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                        tw.Indentation = 3;
                        tw.WriteStartDocument();
                        xsl.Transform(xmldoc, null, tw); //Performa XSLT transformation.
                    }
```

Is there any limit to number of sheets or size of file to transform?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The limit is in the megabytes.  Don't think 15 pages gets you there.  Make sure XML is not corrupted.  From VS Project menu, Project : Add New Item : XML File.  Paste your XML into window.  Errors will show up in Error view just like any other compiler error.

Comment: XML file looks good and have no errors. Even when i manually copy xml and xsl to http://xsltransform.net/ it perfectlly converts into result excel.
just getting the same error on line xsl.Transform(xmldoc, null, tw);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have migrated my project from .net framework 3.5 to .net framework 4.5 and the issue no longer exist.